# how to except a double and int

Tags: java, if-statement

I created this simple calculator. My question is, if someone was to input a double value it would cause the system to crash. How do I make an exception and make it so it excepts a double value as well ?

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double variable ;
    System.out.println("input your first number");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number1 = scan.nextInt();

System.out.println("input your second number");
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number2 = scan2.nextInt();
    int result = number1*number2;
    System.out.println(result);

    }
    
    }
```

Comment: Just write it for doubles. If your user inputs an integer value it can be treated as a double.

Answer (score 0):

```
double number1;
double number2;
try {
    System.out.println("input your first number");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String string1 = scan.nextLine();
    number1 = Double.parseDouble(string1);

    System.out.println("input your second number");
    String string2 = scan.nextLine();
    number2 = Double.parseDouble(string2);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid number");
    return;
}

double result = number1 * number2;

System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **try** + **catch** block to catch Exceptions, and handle them accordingly.

The `try` statement allows you to define a block of code to be tested for errors while it is being executed.

The `catch` statement allows you to define a block of code to be executed, if an error occurs in the try block.

The `try` and `catch` keywords come in pairs. For example:

```
try {
  //  Block of code to try
}
catch(Exception e) {
  //  Block of code to handle errors
}
```

In this case, inserting a double would throw a **NumberFormatException**, an  exception which is thrown when it can't properly format the integer.

Here's what your code is supposed to be:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        double variable ;
        System.out.println("input your first number");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number1 = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("input your second number");
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number2 = scan2.nextInt();
        int result = number1*number2;
        System.out.println(result);
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println("Invalid integer")
    }


    }
    
}
```

...or you can just treat it as a double.